# "TemplateSyntaxError: 'humanize' is not a valid tag library:" in DJango

Tags: python, django, django-registration

While setting up the django-registration module I have run into a bit of trouble. Everything works correctly as far as rendering templates. After trying to test-register I am hit with this error. I do have **Django.contrib.humanize** in the settings.py file. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should post your ``INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS`` setting, the traceback for the error, and your template code.

Comment: Will do on on future questions. I wrote this question out of fustration.

Comment: Didn't work for me either after trying to use it for the first time. Forgot to restart the server  :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As the docs say:

> To activate these filters, add 'django.contrib.humanize' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

So perhaps you should have "django." not "Django." ? See [Django docs on django.contrib.humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/)

Also do you have "{% load humanize %}" in the templates?
You may also want to look at [TemplateSyntaxError: 'settings_tags' is not a valid tag library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4539266/680238)

Comment: I do have in templates but the capital D threw it off. Thanks bunches.